# Problem initializing Reactor Redis with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to get Reactive Redis working with existing application that has normal syncronous Redis implementation running. I can't change all the implementation at once, so I'm trying to get them both work at the same time.

This is what I have previously.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.redis")
public class MemoryCacheConfiguration {
    private String endpoint;
    private int port;

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(this.endpoint, this.port));
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, String> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Serializable.class));
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Serializable.class));
        return template;
    }    
}
```

This is what I'm adding to the file

```
@Bean
public ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory reactiveRedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(endpoint, port);
}

@Bean
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    RedisSerializationContext.RedisSerializationContextBuilder<String, String> builder =
            RedisSerializationContext.newSerializationContext(new StringRedisSerializer());
    RedisSerializationContext<String, String> context =
            builder.value(new StringRedisSerializer()).build();
    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate<>(factory, context);
}
```

If I have ReactiveRedisTemplate in the file defined, I'm getting following error about the duplicate

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: reactiveRedisTemplate,reactiveStringRedisTemplate
```

However, if I remove the definition so that it is blank, I'm getting the following.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

What might be the reason for this, as I haven't defined any reactiveStringRedisTemplate and there is no reference to it in my project, but if I remove my custom one, then it doesn't find any Bean required.

I am using Spring Boot version 2.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

It helped that naming the bean properly where it was used so that it detected the correct template.

As I had this:

```
private final ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> redisReactorTemplate;

@Autowired
public RedisService(ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> redisReactorTemplate) {
      this.redisReactorTemplate = redisReactorTemplate;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
private final ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate;

@Autowired
public RedisService(ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String> reactiveRedisTemplate) {
      this.redisReactorTemplate = reactiveRedisTemplate;
}
```

I don't know the reason it has two possible beans at that point though (expected single matching bean but found 2: reactiveRedisTemplate,reactiveStringRedisTemplate).